# if statement segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am checking to see if a pointer exists and if it does exist then it doesn't point to a NULL/zero value. My code looks like this:

```
if (prior != NULL && *prior){
  //do something
}
```

Where prior is a pointer. However, I am getting a segmentation fault on `*prior`. But I don't understand how this is possible. The if-statement should short circuit if prior is a NULL pointer, so *prior should always work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is not NULL but the pointer point to invalid address.

Comment: If the compiler does not complain about an unknown identifier, the pointer variable **does** exist. Where is your [mcve]? There is no `*prior` in the single line you show.

Comment: The fact that a pointer is non-null doesn't mean you're allowed to dereference it. In fact, you might not even be allowed to compare it to NULL.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara I see, thanks

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara gives the correct answer, but if you want to know why it has an invalid address, you'll have to post more code!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (prior != NULL && *prior){
    //do something
}
```

There are more reasons to segfault than just dereferencing a NULL pointer. The pointer may be not NULL, yet if you are deference an invalid or dangled pointer, your program can still segfault.

Revisit this well-known answer about pointer: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

which also explains why a pointer can be non NULL yet still invalid.

Comment: [Reworking comments into answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) is acceptable behaviour.

Comment: @KenY-N you can't say that it's a rework unless there is a significant time difference between a comment and a more complete answer.

Comment: @artm this is an online community, there are all sorts of people, you don't let your feelings down just because some random unpleasants.

Comment: @fluter absolutely